# Power BI - GroupBy - Top 1 Value (MAX)

Tags: group-by, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

can you help me how I can group by Column 1-7 in Power BI/ DAX and get the Person with the highest Sales based on its group?

I tried groupby in power query and also using the Top Filter N but I can't get the result according to its row grouping from col 1-7.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DsXO-LunDhe3J5SSgXtzeP6JqlQjnYvu86bLab9tGhM/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the **Calculated Table** formula you are looking for:

```
Result = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Raw Data',
    'Raw Data'[Column 1],
    'Raw Data'[Column 2],
    'Raw Data'[Column 3],
    'Raw Data'[Column 4],
    'Raw Data'[Column 5],
    'Raw Data'[Column 6],
    'Raw Data'[Column 7],
    "Person", CALCULATE(
        MIN('Raw Data'[Person]),
        'Raw Data'[Sales] = MAX('Raw Data'[Sales])
    ),
    "Sales", MAX('Raw Data'[Sales])
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you this works! Can you help me how I can count the number of products if I have new column? Group by Column 1-7 --> Max Sales of Person + Total Products of that Sale

Comment: Add `"Total Products of that Sale", CALCULATE(MIN('Raw Data'[Products]), 'Raw Data'[Sales] = MAX('Raw Data'[Sales]))` to SUMMARIZE.

Comment: thank you peter! can you check? the new column shows the actual product not the count? :(

Comment: It shows "Total Products of that (highest) Sale"